# How to extend a class/prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, javascript-objects

Okay, so I have the module pattern of my main class as follows:

```
    Var draggable = {};

    (function(){

     var initialMouseX = undefined;
     var initialMouseY = undefined;
     var startX        = undefined;
     var startY        = undefined;
     var draggedObject = undefined;

     var startDragX    = undefined;
     var startDragY    = undefined;

     var eventHandler  = undefined;
     var canvas        = undefined;

     var that = this;

     this.setCanvasObject = function(cnv){
         canvas = cnv;
     }

     this.setEventHandler = function(eH){
         eventHandler = eH;
     };

     this.setClickable = function(element){
         ...        
     };

     this.setDraggable = function(element){
         ...
     };

     this.startDragMode = function(ev){
        ...
     };

     this.dragMouse = function(ev){
       ....
     };

     this.setPosition = function(dX, dY){
       ...
     };

     this.releaseElement = function() {
      ...
     };
 }).apply(draggable);
```

This is my parent or prototype class using my flavour of the module design pattern.

Here is my child class, using the same module pattern:

```
var toolbarHeader = {};

 (function(){

         this.__proto__ = draggable;

         var that = this;

         this.__proto__.startDragMode = function(ev){
             var evt = ev || window.event;
             var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

             target = target.parentNode;
             that.startDrag(target);
             initialMouseX = evt.clientX;
             initialMouseY = evt.clientY;

             eventHandler.addEventSimple(document,'mousemove', that.dragMouse);
             eventHandler.addEventSimple(document,'mouseup', that.releaseElement);                    
         };


 }).apply(toolbarHeader);
```

What i want to do is my toolbarHeader class to overwrite the parent method and in rest use the parents methods as they are.

Currently it issues an error because it cannot find that.releaseElement, that.startDrag and that.dragMouse.

What am i doing wrong? Is this how i should be using inheritance? Is this a good design?

Comment: Why do you call them "classes" when they are just simple module objects? There is no instantiation or constructors involved.

Comment: You should not overwrite `draggable.startDragMode` from `toolbarHeader`.

Comment: If you're using `__proto__`, your solution is probably wrong (`__proto__` is actually deprecated).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2bdusmev/

Comment: @AndrewEvt  but that does not keep my modular pattern.

Comment: @FelixKling well sorry for wanting to be too clever. You're flagged ;)

Comment: Because I like my code structured in modules, and because it is not incorrect, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: @FelixKling okay, how would you rewrite this? Could you give me an answer? The purpose for using modules here is for extensibility and for the power it gives me to use them anywhere without too much hustle for namespaces and instantiation. If you can point me or answer with a solid design, I will be grateful.

Comment: Checking out the docs is fairly easy for me, but having the opinion of experts is not, so please be constructive, i am mostly a backend developer :)

Comment: So, nothing practical, just "text book" theories...

Comment: That's no thing of frontend or backend. It's hard to give you a concrete and constructive answer, because the code-pieces you showed are just a big clutter of concepts and problems; and we can only guess what your code looks like, and therefore how you try to use these things. For example in toolbarHeader: what are `initialMouseX` and Y, or `eventHandler`? These can't be the variables you declared in the other snippet, since these are "private". then, parts of `draggable` feel like a DI-Container, parts like a util-lib, and the rest, ... what is this whole mess, and why are the mixed together?

Comment: http://metaduck.com/08-module-pattern-inheritance.html,  to just prove the fact that I don't believe any of the commenters above know how to code, this is from the following google search: https://www.google.ro/search?q=javascript+class+or+module&oq=javascript+class+vs+module&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2.7181j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8